# Ionic segment button with icon and text to make like tab bar

Tags: ionic3

I try to achieve ion segment button with icon and text like tab bar but getting differently.
what i have tried so far

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-segment style="background:#3B6593">
    <ion-segment-button style="color:white">
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      Heizöl
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="diesel_10" style=color:white>
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      Diesel
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="benzin_e5" style=color:white>
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      Benzin E5
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="benzin_e10" style=color:white>
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      Benzin E10
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="benzin_e10" style=color:white>
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      Benzin E10
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</ion-footer>
```

[image]

I have try to get it with super tabs like this

```
<ion-footer>
    <super-tabs toolbarColor="light">
        <super-tab [root]="tab1Root" title="Home" icon="home"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [root]="tab2Root" title="Uneverasalseite" icon="ios-globe"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [root]="tab3Root" title="News" icon="logo-designernews"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [root]="tab4Root" title="Tickcharts" icon="ios-stats"></super-tab>
        <super-tab [root]="tab5Root" title="RPI" icon="ios-pulse"></super-tab>
      </super-tabs>
</ion-footer>
```

the result would be

[image]

but here i need to style this it is difficult to reduce tab bar height and adjust text size.

Comment: clarify your question . You like tab bar mean?

Comment: Yes i want to get tabs page, what happened actually i have side menu and tabs. I want to keep tab bar in every page that i can't get it so i tried with ion segments to get it something like that. Is it possible to get it ion segments.

Comment: yea its possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Need to change `.html`**

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-segment style="background:#3B6593">
      <ion-segment-button style="color:white" icon-left>
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
        <div style="margin-top: -20px !important; ">
          Heizöl
        </div>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="diesel_10" style=color:white>
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
        <div style="margin-top: -20px !important; ">
          Diesel
        </div>

      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="benzin_e5" style=color:white>
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
        <div style="margin-top: -20px !important; ">
          Benzin E5
        </div>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="benzin_e10" style=color:white>
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
        <div style="margin-top: -20px !important; ">
          Benzin E10
        </div>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="benzin_e10" style=color:white>
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
        <div style="margin-top: -20px !important; ">
          Benzin E10
        </div>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-footer>
```

**And also need to override `$segment-button-md-height` in variable.scss like**

```
$segment-button-md-height:55px;
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and i have tried your snippet i can not get text under icon. I have increased button height also.

Comment: $segment-button-md-height:60px; declare in variable.scss App Material Design Variables section

Comment: But the tab bar is very height. If i reduce height from 75px to 55px text is disappeared.

Comment: yea you need to be trick like margin-top:-20px; and $segment-button-md-height:55px;

Comment: Yes definitely but here i have one more problem that i have segments in other page also. I can not declare this in variables.scss.

Comment: For this reason you need to remove from variable.scss and give ion-segment inline height or  add in corosponding .scss ion-segment-button{
   height: 55px !important;
 }

Comment: One more question is it possible to remove segment indicator when it is active  or at least change indicator color because if you click on segment it goes to tabs page so i s´do not need here indicator. Can we make it with out touching global theme variable.

Comment: .segment-activated{
    border-color: red !important;
  }

Comment: Hi Utpaul sorry to disturb you again. I have segments top and bottom of the same page. Is it possible to overwrite differently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
<ion-segment-button style="color:white">
    <ion-icon name="custom_name_of_icon"></ion-icon>
      Heizöl
</ion-segment-button>
```

Then Inspect element after ionic serve in browser.
A new class associated with the element will come.
Then with css after or before effect you will place the image on custom icon.

It is tested and tried method.